# Matlab function return value

Tags: matlab, return-value

I have one program that has function and the problem, return value, it has too many output.

Like exempley: y = text the answer comes up

```
Error in text (line 2)

if nargin == 0 

Output argument "array" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "
C:\Users\name\Documents\MATLAB\text.m>text".
```

The program text.m reads a txt file that contains a couple of names and numbers like

exemple:

John doughlas 15986

Filip duch 357852

and so on. The program convert them to 15986 Doughlas John and so on.

```
function array = text(~) 
if nargin == 0 
dirr = '.';
end
answer = dir(dirr);  
k=1;
while k <= length(answer) 
    if answer(k).isdir 
        answer(k)=[]; 
    else
        filename{k}=answer(k).name;
        k=k+1;
    end
 end
chose=menu( 'choose file',filename);
namn = char(filename(chose));  
fid = fopen(namn, 'r');    
R = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s');  
x=-1;                                            
k=0;                                               
while x <= 24                                  
      x = k + 1;                                    
      All = [R{3}{x},'   ',R{1}{x},' ',R{2}{x}];
      disp(All)                                     
      k = k + 1;                                   
end                                                
fclose(fid);
```

Is there anyway to fix the problem without starting over from scratch?

Grateful for all the answers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You specify the function output argument in the definition, but you don't assign anything to it in the function body.

For example, in

```
function y = student(j)
```

your output is `y`. So you have to assign something to `y`.

Read more about [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) in MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you, I figure out where to put it but cant figure out the text.m, it has to many output.

Comment: You can return multiple outputs from a function with `[x,y,z] = functionname(...)`. Or you can combine all outputs into a cell array or a structure. Read the documentation, it's clearly explained. And don't call the function `text`, since there is a build-in MATLAB function with this name.

Comment: Sorry but I cant find the result I am looking for maybe I am just to close to see it or I am blind. But I read the documentation and I got some results but not what I am looking for.

Like exemple:

    y=25
    y= numbers name1,2,3,4,5 and so on
    y=
    numbers name1
    y =
    numbers name2 and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand what you need. Please explain in details what result do you expect. Better in a new question, since you've already accepted this one. You can refer to this question with a link.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example.

The first part is to create a function called 'functionA' in a filename 'functionA.m'. Then put the following code inside:

```
    function  result = functionA(N,alpha)
    result = 5;
    return
    end
```

The second part is to create another Matlab file(i.e. upto you to name it) or you can use the Matlab command window even. Then run the following code:

```
    getresult = functionA(100,10);
    getresult
```

After running you get the following answer:

```
    ans = 
          5
```